# What does this JS syntax below actually mean?

Tags: javascript

Has anyone come across something like this `const foo = (var1, var2) => bar` in JS. I was going through someone else's code and came across something like this, not sure what this code does exactly but the line that precedes this is a declaration for bar `let bar;`. Does anyone have any ideas what this means

Comment: It's the syntax for creating arrow functions.

Comment: [Arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score -1):

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp

its for arrow functions, so you can write shorter function syntax

Comment: please use MDN when possible for javascript-related references, not some random webpage.

Comment: dude, its w3schools not a random webpage. but sure. ill keep it in mind

Comment: Does the variable arrow mean it'll assign whatever it returns to that variable though?